# Importing data from MYSQL to HIVE using SQOOP

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to copy data from `MySQL` to `HIVE` using `SQOOP`. However, I am getting below error even though I have set `HIVE_CONF_DIR` variable in `bashrc` file. Below is my code:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampleOne \
--username root \
-P \
--table SAMPLEDATA  \
--target-dir /WithFieldss_T11  \
--hive-import \
--hive-table sampleone.customers
```

variable in **bashrc** file:

```
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hive/conf
```

**Error**:

```
ERROR hive.HiveConfig: Could not load org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf. Make sure HIVE_CONF_DIR is set correctly.
18/04/29 20:48:53 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf
```

What else I need to add/modify here ??

Comment: Did you `source` the bashrc before running sqoop command?

Comment: yeah i did that but of no use...

Comment: Based on your other questions, I am not sure why sqoop stopped working. Are you on a different machine without Hive installed?

Comment: No, I have everything installed in single machine only and working perfectly. Do you have any other workaround ?

Comment: Is my code correct ?

Comment: I think so... It's been years since I've use Sqoop. Can you please show the output of `ls -la $HIVE_CONF_DIR`?

Comment: Its all the jar files. Its a very lengthy list. Do you want to see it ?

Comment: I feel like your hive conf directory shouldn't contain any jar files. It should be the hive-site.xml and a few other shell files only

Comment: yeah my path in bashrc was incorrect. Now i changed my path and now its showing hive-site.xml in list. Let me run my code once again

Comment: I tried but still the same error

Answer (score 2):

add this in ~/.bashrc 
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/hive/lib/*
and copy the respective hive-common jar like hive-common-3.1.1.jar for hive3.1
to "sqoop/lib" folder